# Hadoop use-case scenario

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, hadoop2

I would like to have some expert views on the use of a Big Data platform like Hadoop in one of my project scenarios. I am a complete novice in this technology although I understand databases like MySQL well.

We are creating a product which would be used to analyse data from social media. So the input data would be a large volume of tweets, facebook posts, user profiles, YouTube data and data from blogs etc. On top of this I would be having a web application to help me view and analyse this data. As the requirement makes it clear, I would be needing a sort of real time system. So if I have a tweet coming in, I would like to have it available to my web app readily for processing. Batch data processing may not be a suitable choice for my application.

My questions are:

- Is a Hadoop engine a good choice for me?
- What are the parameter I should base my decision on?
- Is it also a good option to use a Multi Cluster MySQL engine as opposed to Hadoop?
- Is there any benchmarking in terms of Size and velocity of data in which Hadoop becomes a good choice?

Answer (score 6):

Hadoop is not appropriate for near real time / interactive analysis.  Hadoop was designed to do big batch processing of say a few hours of data plus.  I used to use Hadoop to process any dataset that was around 10 GB or more (which is still a bit overkill), once it get's to 100 GB then you defo want something like Hadoop.

Now my recommendation would be for Spark as this is much more modern, much faster, more flexible, more powerful, and has a SparkStreaming module for achieving closer to real time analysis. Read all about it! https://spark.apache.org/

Answer (score 1):

In this case I prefer the Lambda Architecture.

With Lambda Architecture you have two routes: A fast route with a noSQL database for the current informations, and a batch route with hadoop-hdfs for the archive data, and with a merge component you can merge the two datasources in one query, so you receive a whole amount of data, which is near real time.

http://lambda-architecture.net/

Image about lambda architecture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eofRW.png

We created a PoC Project with Lambda Architecture (also for Twitter analysis), and its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Spark will be the best solution for your problem.You can also look other in-memory databases.